# How would I restore security prompts in the Java Control Panel in a script?

Tags: java, windows, vbscript

This will be for Windows 7 x64 systems running JRE7u67.

Running javacpl.exe located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` starts javaw.exe and gives you a control panel for various JRE settings. The security tab has a button labeled "Restore Security Prompts" that we need to click and we need to do it for a large number of computers.

I've been unable to find documentation citing this button's function as related to any property in deployment.properties. I've also looked up command line switches for java, javaw, and javacpl, but have found nothing related to this.

We've been able to script the JRE7u67 installations with every setting we need except for restoring the security prompts. How can we go about including this in a Windows script?

Comment: Try using a tool like [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to determine what changes the process makes to files and/or the registry when the button is clicked. Then just replicate those changes using a script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html

It was in the documentation all along, I just missed it. We can write a script that just adds the line:

`deployment.insecure.jres=PROMPT`